# get earliest date for each id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

given the following

```
table1
id,name
1,test1
2,test2
3,test3

tablePrt
id,date
1,5/1/11
1,5/3/11
3,3/1/11

tableOnl
id,date
1,5/4/11
1,5/15/11

tableSrv
id,date
1,5/13/11
1,5/1/11
2,4/1/11
```

what are some ways to get the single earliest date for each id from all 3 tables plus the name of the id that's in table1?

so the result from above should look like the following:

```
test1, 5/1/11
test2, 4/1/11
test3, 3/1/11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       MIN(tbls.DATE) 
FROM   table1 t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id, 
                          DATE 
                   FROM   tableprt 
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT id, 
                          DATE 
                   FROM   tableonl 
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT id, 
                          DATE 
                   FROM   tablesrv) tbls 
         ON t1.id = tbls.id 
GROUP  BY t1.id
```

Note:  <strike>no need to do UNION ALL here</strike>  As Martin Noted Even though UNION ALL isn't required it may be faster

Comment: `UNION ALL` can give a plan [with lower estimated cost](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LHLON.jpg) from my exceedingly quick test.

Comment: @Martin doh. Of course UNION ALL doesn't do a dedupe and since we're looking for min UNION ALL Would be better